# Configuring NGINX to work with SAML Signing Certificate

Tags: azure, nginx, certificate, single-sign-on, saml

I've built an app using PHP (Laravel), and now we've deployed it to a client who wants to use Azure Single Sign On rather than the apps native username/password functionality.

The plan is for them to handle the SSO authentication via App Registration, and then send user details via a SAML request.

However the 'SAMLResponse' I get is encoded. They have sent me a .cer file (and an XML file for some reason), and I think I need to apply these to the server, but I don't know how.

The below is the setup their end, and I've red highlighted the files they've sent me.

I have full control over the server, which is Ubuntu 18.04 running NGINX. They also handle the SSL side of things separately, so NGINX is currently listening on port 80.

[image: SAML configuration]

Comment: The SAMLResponse is base64 encoded and deflated. The Federation Metadata XML is to allow you to trust the SAMLResponse by validating any signature using the Certificate.

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed to know. I was given incorrect information in that the certificate was needed to decode the SAMLResponse, but as you say it was just base64 encoded. Thanks so much!